# Program freeze after input?

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop, freeze

After the user inputs their choices, the program seems to offer the same choices again, followed by it completely freezing. It's only set on there to give them the option once (I believe) and then follow the selections below. Instead it seems to revert back to the top, and then just freeze for some odd reason. Tried figuring it out for a while, but no avail.

```
public void init() //Initialize method {

    setSize(1000, 800); //Set size
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN); //Set background
}    


public void paint(Graphics g)  {

    super.paint(g); //Start paint method
    g.setFont(new Font("Veranda", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Hello", 250, 25); //top display message
    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like a custom loop count or an infinite? 1. Custom 2. Infinite"); //test choice
    n = Integer.parseInt(number);

    while (n>0 || n<2)
    if (n==1) { 
            String number2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times would you like to loop?");
            integer = Integer.parseInt(number2);
            while (integer>0)
                while (x < integer) {   
                    g.drawString("hi", 200, y); 
                    x+=1;
                    y = y+40; //test
                }//end while
    }//end if 
    else if (n==2)  {
        while (true); //im aware this is an endless loop. Can't find anything more stable for an endless one, so its just there for now..
    }//end if   
    else;
    g.drawString("Please pick a valid choice", 200, 200);               
}//end paint
}//end
```

Comment: Add a tag that says Java so people who know it can help--and so your code will be colorized.

Comment: `while (integer > 0)` looks highly suspicious. By Java parsing rules, it contains one statement--the next wwile loop.

Comment: `while (true)` is an infinite loop: `while (false)` does nothing, but needless to say it's confusing!

Comment: while (true); does something - it never stops and breaks your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understood

```
while (integer>0) {
    while (x < integer)
    {   
        g.drawString("hi", 200, y); 
        x+=1;
        y = y+40; //test
    }//end while
    integer --; // <-- This is missing
}
break; // <-- Also missing
```

The inner while ends when x = integer
but integer is always > 0
you have to do `integer --` at the end of the outer loop
So it can go to 0 at some point

Please use proper indentation...  it helps

I edited the code... see where I put the 'integer --'

try converting your `while(n>0 || n<2)` to `if(n>0 && n<2)`

Try not using `while` instead of `if`, it creates less confusion

Add brackets `{}` for all your code blocks, easier to read, hence easier to debug, maybe you'll figure it out by just doing that

Also is the `;` after the last `else` intended?

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean, sorry. If you could kind of expand on that, it would be great :) And sorry about the indentation, I'm kind of new to java :/ I'm more or less learning it on my own, as my teacher is no help for any of this.

Comment: never mind, that didn't seem to fix the problem. I put integer --; after where you showed me, and nothing changed.. :/

Comment: What input do you give it... 1?

Comment: You need a break-out condition of the main while loop

Comment: Yea I gave it an input of 1, still didnt work.. I've just taken out the while for now, cant get it working :/